# Elastic_search function for deleting all records except a spastic set

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to delete all records from a specified index except for a specific set. Is there such a function in elastic_search?

I tried to use `delete_by_query` function but could not get it to work as desired. Below is a snippet of what I tried. I basically want to have an array of ids instead of only one id at a time.

```
POST /myindex/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match": {
            "id": {
              "query": [12345,67890]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am new to elastic_search, but in `SQL` terms I want to something like the following query:

```
DELETE * FROM <my-index> WHERE <id> != <listOfIds>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good start!! You can do it like you suggest with a `terms` query:

```
POST /myindex/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "id": [
              12345,
              67890
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer@Val. 

I did get the query I used first to work, I think I just had a syntax mistake somewhere, is there a preferred way to do it though? 

Just to clarify your answer works as desired and the [above query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73435142/15174709) as well, I just want to know if there is pros/cons I should know about.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped! The way it's done is perfectly legit and delete by query works with any kind of queries, it just allows you to delete exactly what the query selects. If you had time series data, though, and wanted to regularly delete the oldest data, there would be another easier way to achieve it using [Index Lifecycle Management](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html)